# Namespace an admin area

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As an example, lets say I'm creating a twitter(-ish) clone.

---

- A User has_many Tweets
- A Tweet belongs to a User

---

- Users can create tweets
- Users can edit and delete their own tweets
- Users who are admins can edit and delete all tweets
- Users who are admins can edit and delete users who aren't admins

---

Here's my tweets controller:

```
class TweetsController < ActionController
    before_action :set_tweet, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :only_admins_and_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


    def edit
        # edits the tweet
    end 

    def update
        # updates the tweet
    end 

    def destroy
        # destroys the tweet
    end

    private
        ### security
        def only_admins_and_owner
             redirect_to root_url unless current_user.is_admin? || current_user === @tweet.user
        end
        ###

        def set_tweet
            @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

My users controller:

```
class UsersController < ActionController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :only_admins_and_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


    def edit
        # edits the user
    end 

    def update
        # updates the user
    end 

    def destroy
        # destroys the user
    end

    private
        ### security
        def only_admins_and_user
             redirect_to root_url unless current_user.is_admin? || current_user === @user
        end
        ###

        def set_user
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

And here's my panels controller. Not sure if this is the right way to do it to be honest. What do you think of my naming conventions? I haven't called it AdminController because by **panels** (plural) I am refering to the multiple panels in the admin area, the user panel (for displaying all of the users and offering administration controls in the view) and the tweets panel:

```
class PanelsController < ActionController
    before_action :only_admins
    def users
        @users = User.all
    end

    def tweets
       @tweets = Tweet.all
    end

    private
        ### security
        def only_admins
             redirect_to root_url unless current_user.is_admin?
        end
        ###
 end
```

If you think this controller setup is okay, how should I configure my routes to use these actions?

My routes file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users, except: [:index] do
        resources :tweets, except: [:index]
    end
end
```

Now the above works okay if I am a normal user CRUDing away at user and tweets but how should I namespace my Panels controller?

When an admin is viewing users in the panels controller's users view, I want the URLs to look like this:

```
/control_panel/users
/control_panel/tweets
```

and when editing in the admin area:

```
/control_panel/users/12/edit
/control_panel/users/12/tweets/142/edit
```

but when a user is editing their own user or tweet:

```
/users/12/edit
/users/12/tweets/142/edit
```

This is because the `panels` administration views are vastly different to the user views, but the functionality of editing, updating and deleting is identical so I want to use the already existing actions. Am I doing it right? Not sure how else I could do it, other than adding loads of actions to to the panels controller, `def_user_update` and `def_tweet_update` and so on for every single resource. Doesn't feel very nice...

So how should I configure my routes?

I guess I want to sort of create an optional namespace around my two nested routes...
Maybe a concern? If I do that, though, I get an `uninitialized constant Panel` error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same controller, which is something I don't really recommend, you can use a scope.

```
resources :users, except: [:index] do
  resources :tweets, except: [:index]
end
scope :control_panel do
  resources :users, expect: [:index] do
    resources :tweets, except: [:index]
  end
end
```

This gets you all the routes that you want, and they all point to the `UsersController` and `TweetsController`

What I recommend instead is using a different controller for admins. You can achieve this with namespaces.

```
namespace :control_panel do
  resources :users, etc: ...
end
```

You then keep site user's concerns in `TweetsController` and control panel concerns in `ControlPanel::TweetsController` in app/controllers/control_panel/tweets_controller.rb

You can read more about namespaces and routing [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).